# Android QR Barcode using Media Player

Tags: android

I am developing an application which consists of Qrbarcode reader as well as  MediaPlayer,Here is my problem?

1. QR Barcode is successfully working for me.
2. when QRBarcode is scanned it will show some URl right.
3. The URL which is displayed Should Run Mediaplayer.

Answer (score 1):

Guy, what's your problem? I Didn't understand

Everyone knows that you can do what you want with AZTEC codes (aka QRCode).
Yeah, you right, this is possible, after scann ome code, you put like URL on MEDIAPLAYER.

regards, reply that if you want some solutions.